# OpenGL - glusphere not smooth

Tags: c, opengl

I have been experimenting with the arguments to glusphere(). The problem is that the sphere is not smooth, and looks more like a blot. Right now, my call looks like this:

```
       glPushMatrix();

       glTranslatef(0.1, 0.1, 0.0);

       GLUquadricObj *quadric;
       quadric = gluNewQuadric();

       gluSphere(quadric, .02 , 32 , 16);
       glPopMatrix();
```

Any suggestions as to what looks not right with this code snippet will be appreciated. My understanding is that the higher the value of 3rd and 4th argument, slices and stacks, respectively, the smoother the edges of the sphere will be.

EDIT:

Changing the translation coordinates to (0.08, 0.08, 0) results in a much smoother sphere.

Comment: Can you put snapshots?

Comment: What is the lighting setup in your scene ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: I am not using lightning.

Comment: That's why your sphere looks like a blot. As per my understanding you ll only be able to see a circle kind of object.